# csv-like format that is compatible in both US and Europe

Tags: csv

Countries that use the point as a decimal mark (US, UK, China, India, etc.) use this format as csv:

```
value,value,value
```

Countries that use the comma as a decimal mark (Germany, Russia, France, South America, etc.) use this format as csv:

```
value;value;value
```

I've had some problems with (IIRC) MS Office 2003 in this regard.

So the question:

Is there a format that is as simple to create and parse as csv that does not suffer from an incompatibility between major world regions and can be read by MS Office and Libreoffice?

Edit:

I noticed that Libreoffice assues tabs as seperators when importing from csv:

```
value<tab>value<tab>value
```

Is that format usable in MS Office for US and Europe?

Comment: yes, it's called "don't use human readable formatting". `12345` is the same no matter where you go. `123,45` is... what? two numbers with a comma between? or one number, with euro formatting? There is no "standard" csv. There's just whatever format any particular app accepts.

Comment: Afaik you can specify the separator character when loading a CSV file. So you should be fine with any symbol, that is not used within your values. So if your values are just numbers, you should be fine with using `X` as a separator, e.g..

Comment: You have to make your code independent from users culture, you can use your own culture for the piece of code you write and read csv.

Comment: @Marc B, E-Bat: I need a format that can be read with Excel/Libreoffice and by my own application.

Answer (score 0):

If you care only about Excel, then you can do this trick, add this line at the beginning of the CSV file:

```
sep=;
```

It can be other char, but I think ; is the most intuitive and doesn't cause confusion with decimal separators.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! It is call [tab-seperated values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab-separated_values).

Answer (score -1):

The best answer for this problem is still XML, which is the solution adopted by both LibreOffice and Excel file formats. They contain headers informing encoding, collate and other locale settings.